# document ready in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, document-ready

I want to fire some jQuery code when you click on a checkbox. The problem is that when I click on a selectbox first time when the page is loaded, nothing happens. But when I click again, the jQuery-code is executed. I've tried to set angular.element(ready) as below, but it dont work:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        $http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/test/test')
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.test = data.data;
        });
        $scope.testa = function() {
                $('.checkboxfisk').click(function() {
                var fish = $(this).attr('id');
                alert(fish);    
                });

        };
});

<tr ng-repeat="info in test"><td>{{info.stracka}}</td><td>{{info.tid}}</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="{{info.id}}" class="checkboxfisk" ng-click="testa()"></tr>
```

Comment: if you want to "fire jquery code" on click, why you need angular to do anything?

Comment: you can use the nginit directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: @Dalorzo: Because Im going to use the data that jQuery gets for my with Angular.

Comment: "Don't even use jQuery. Don't even include it. It will hold you back."  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: definitely read the link @isherwood provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to interact with the DOM in Angular is to create your own custom directive. You can then wire up the jQuery handler in the postLink function of you directive (which Angular runs when it builds the page on load). Your handler will be there and waiting when the page is ready.

Take a look at Angular's documentation for directives and give it a shot:

[AnuglarJS: Developer Guide: Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Looking at your example, though, that may be too much. There's no need to have jQuery listen for the click event at all. You just need to remove the jQuery wrapper around your function definition and let Angular handle the click event itself:

```
$scope.testa = function(id) {
    alert(id);
};
```

And then modify your `ng-click` attribute to pass the id in the expression:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       id="{{info.id}}" 
       class="checkboxfisk" 
       ng-click="testa(info.id)">
```

Comment: Im just a newbie when It comes to AngularJS, so I don't know how directives works. Do you have an solution for non pro developer?

Comment: @user500468 - The solution for a non-pro developer is to read the documentation, understand what is going on, and still do it the right way. I linked to the documentation so you can take a look and get started.

Comment: Thank you. Im going to give it a shot.

Comment: @user500468 - I just updated my answer as your problem may be easily solved without using jQuery at all.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular way to render items is different from "On DOM Ready" that is why we need to treat these as 2 separate things.

Angular could render items after DOM is ready, this could happen for example if there is an AJAX call(`$http.get`) and that is why a directive may be the recommended approach.

Try something like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" chk-Sample="" >

<script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {}]);

myApp.directive("chkSample", function() {
    return {
            restrict: "A", //A - means attribute
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
               $(element).click(function() {
                 var fish = $(this).attr('id');
                 alert(fish);    
               });
            }
        };
});

...
```

By declaring the directive `myApp.directive("chkSample",...` as an attribute `chk-Sample=""` every time angulare generates the input element it will execute the link function in the directive.

Answer (score 0):

The direct reason why it runs after second click is that in your ng-click handler you use jQuery click() function, which binds the click handler, within you execute alert. So after first click, you only bind the function, but not execute it. After it is bound, the next click executes it. Anyway, like it was said before, it should be done using directives.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right way, but the below code worked for me:-

```
    $timeout(function(){
     if(condition){
       /*
             code you want to execute */
        }

    });
```